# Converting a list of encodings to some sort of array in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to loop through all the items in the items, but first I must to cast to appropriate type which I fail.

```
'  Dim arr As EncodingInfo 
        Dim arr As List(Of Encoding) = DirectCast(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings(), List(Of Encoding))
        ' Error 1   Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Text.EncodingInfo' 
        '  cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Text.Encoding)'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
Dim arr As List(Of Text.EncodingInfo) = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncodings().ToList
```

should work